# Import xlsx files in Odoo via Python script

Tags: python, import, odoo-9

The code below is a function which is execute when i press import products button in Odoo. This script imports products in Odoo from a csv file. The csv file can be uploaded first and then i click the import button.
What i can't do is that when i upload xlsx file and click import i get warning that the file is not valid.
Can someone help me how to enable to import also from xlsx file?

```
@api.one
def action_import(self):
    ctx = self._context
    data = base64.b64decode(self.data)
    file_input = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
    file_input.seek(0)
    row = []
    result = {}
    if self.delimeter:
        delimeter = str(self.delimeter)
    else:
        delimeter = ','
    fieldnames = ['supplier_default_code', 'name', 'product_brand', 'supplier', 'standard_price', 'list_price',
                  'internal_category', 'spare_part', 'service_part', 'default_code', 'supplierinfo_product_name',
                  'rrp_price', 'min_qty', 'weight', 'net_weight', 'volume', 'height', 'width', 'depth', 'delay',
                  'warranty_type', 'warranty', 'sale_delay', 'description', 'description_sale',
                  'description_delivery', 'ean']
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_input, delimiter=delimeter, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    try:
        row.extend(reader)
    except Exception:
        raise exceptions.Warning(_("Not a valid file!"))
    keys = row[0]
    self.create_products_from_array(row)
```

Comment: You can't read`xlsx` using `csv module`. To read `xlsx` search for **python xlsx**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it looks like you're expecting `csv.DictReader` to cope with an `.xlsx` file. But that is something completely different from a `.csv` file. The fact that Excel can open them both doesn't mean they are interchangeable, or somehow the same.

You could try using the module `xlrd`. But it will be a completely different implementation; the module won't provide a drop-in replacement for `csv.DictReader`.

The only other alternative is to preprocess the `.xlsx` file and transform it into the `.csv` that your code expects. You could use `xlrd` for this, or you could write a VBA macro in Excel to do it; in fact there may be a dozen ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to implement this code, Source [XLS to Dict Reader using xlrd](https://gist.github.com/mdellavo/639082)

```
try
    import xlrd

    def XLSDictReader(f, sheet_index=0):
        data    = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        book    = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
        sheet   = book.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)

        def item(i, j):
            return (sheet.cell_value(0,j), sheet.cell_value(i,j))

        return ( dict(item(i,j) for j in range(sheet.ncols)) \
                 for i in range(1, sheet.nrows) )

except ImportError:
XLSDictReader = None
```